# Can't create a shortcut key, even with Karabiner_Elements

Tags: macos, keyboard, karabiner, json

macOS: Ventura 13.3.1 (a)
Keyboard:Kinesis Advantage 360
Software: Karabiner-Elements 14.12.0

**Issue:**

Trying to create a shortcut key that moves an active window to one of three screens, without using the standard modifier keys, ⌘⇧⌥⌃. I want to use Function key 24 with 's','d','f','c'.

On the Adv360 keyboard, I Modified a blank Kinesis key to return function key 24.  Karabiner-EventViewer verified this is working, the key returns 'F24'.

First attempt: System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > All Applications. However, I couldn't get system to recognize my 'f24' key.

Second attempt: Use Karabiner-Elements to create a complex modification. Here's the code:

```
 {
  "title": "Mac OS /w Kinesis Adv360. Move active window to different display",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "F24 + S/D/F/C to move the active window to different displays",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "simultaneous": [
              {
                "key_code": "f24"
              },
              {
                "key_code": "s"
              }
            ],
            "simultaneous_options": {
              "detect_key_down_uninterruptedly": true,
              "key_down_order": "strict",
              "key_up_order": "strict_inverse"
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_arrow",
              "modifiers": ["right_shift", "right_command", "right_control", "left_option"]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "simultaneous": [
              {
                "key_code": "f24"
              },
              {
                "key_code": "d"
              }
            ],
            "simultaneous_options": {
              "detect_key_down_uninterruptedly": true,
              "key_down_order": "strict",
              "key_up_order": "strict_inverse"
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "up_arrow",
              "modifiers": ["right_shift", "right_command", "right_control", "left_option"]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "simultaneous": [
              {
                "key_code": "f24"
              },
              {
                "key_code": "f"
              }
            ],
            "simultaneous_options": {
              "detect_key_down_uninterruptedly": true,
              "key_down_order": "strict",
              "key_up_order": "strict_inverse"
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "right_arrow",
              "modifiers": ["right_shift", "right_command", "right_control", "left_option"]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "simultaneous": [
              {
                "key_code": "f24"
              },
              {
                "key_code": "c"
              }
            ],
            "simultaneous_options": {
              "detect_key_down_uninterruptedly": true,
              "key_down_order": "strict",
              "key_up_order": "strict_inverse"
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "down_arrow",
              "modifiers": ["right_shift", "right_command", "right_control", "left_option"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

- Verified that the keystrokes are being read correctly in the Karabiner-EventViewer.
- Verified that the shortcuts are working as intended when triggered directly.
- Checked the log files (console_user_server.log, grabber_agent.log, and overser_agent.log), but they did not provide useful information for this issue.

**Request for Help:**

I am seeking assistance in determining why my complex modification is not working as intended. Any guidance on how to further troubleshoot this issue, or any suggestions for changes to my configuration, would be greatly appreciated.